# Passar o data-id="@milestones.Codigo" para uma modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

O meu sistema deve funcionar da seguinte maneira:

Ao clicar no botão destacado a vermelho na imagem abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele abre esse modal aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso já acontece, porém agora preciso que ao clicar na primeira imagem, ele pegue o `data-id="@milestones.Codigo"` e salve no campo `CodigoMilestone`.

Botão que chama a modal Atividade:

```
<button class="btn btn-default AddAtividade" data-id="@milestones.Codigo"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
```

Script que abre o modal:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".AddAtividade").click(function () {
    $("#modal").load("AddAtividade", function () {
        $(".modal").modal();
    })
}); 
})
```

Como é que posso fazer isso?

Comment: Deve ser alguma coisa parecida com isso:
`var id = $(this).attr("data-id");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poderia fazer algo assim.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".AddAtividade").click(function () {

    var codigoMilestone = $(this).attr("data-id");

    $("#modal").load("AddAtividade", function () {

        $("#meuInputId").val(codigoMilestone);

        $(".modal").modal();
    })
}); 
})
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou.